# Showing that $(a_n^2)$ is Cauchy implies that $(a_n)$ is Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis

I am confusing myself here I think. I have already shown that $a_n$ Cauchy implies that $a_n^2$ is Cauchy, but I am not sure how to go about proving the converse, as I believe it to be true. I know that Cauchy iff convergent implies bounded, but I am not sure how to use this.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there are no restrictions, $(a_n^2)$ Cauchy does not imply $(a_n)$ is Cauchy:  Let $a_n=(-1)^n$.

**Remark:** The "sign" issue is the only obstruction. Let $a_n\ge 0$ for all large enough $n$.  If $(a_n^2)$ is Cauchy, then so is $(a_n)$. For if $(a_n^2)$ converges to $b$, then $(a_n)$ converges.

Comment: Ah! Precisely, thank you André

Comment: What about $(a_n^3)$?

Comment: Man you beat me to it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not true. Take the sequence $a_{n}=(-1)^{n}$. Then $a_{n}^{2}=1$ for all $n$ which is clearly Cauchy. But $(a_{n})$ is not.